# Что значит строка с методом super() в шаблоне создания класса Python?

Tags: python-3.x, ооп, классы

В редакторе Sublime Text 3 при написании слова "Class" и нажатию [TAB] после этого редактор выдает шаблон использования класса. Я относительно недавно начал изучать ООП в Python и поэтому **не пойму, что означает 4-ая строка**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что в Python3.x вместо конструкции `super(ClassName, self).__init__()` можно использовать укороченную конструкцию, которая будет выполнять то же самое: `super().__init__()`

Comment: А ещё, если в конструктор родительского класса нужно передать какие-то аргументы (например в `PySide2` при написании виждета на основе готового, нужно передавать параметр `parent` для сохранения цепочки потомков (не кидайтесь сильно камнями, не знаю как правильней тут выразиться) ), можно это сделать таким образом: `super().__init__(arg_0, arg_1, ..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Python есть метод super(), который обычно применяется к объектам.
Его главная задача это возможность использования в классе потомке, методов класса-родителя.

```
    # Родительский класс

 class A(object):

def __init__(self):
    print(u'конструктор класса A')

 # Потомок класса А
class B(A):

def __init__(self):
    print(u'конструктор класса B')
    super(B,self).__init__()
```

Смысл примера заключается в том, что Python автоматически (сам по себе) не запустит родительский конструктор, поскольку мы его переопределили в классе B… Поэтому методом super() мы явно вызываем родительский конструктор.

Кто-то посчитает код избыточным, ведь приходиться ссылаться на текущий класс чтобы запустить методы родителя, как стало известно в Python версии 3.0 это проблема решена, метод super() будет вызываться без аргументов.

Кстати существует альтернативная реализация тех же самых действий, как еще ее называют в старом стиле:

```
   class A:
def __init__(self):
    print(u'конструктор класса A')

class B(A):

def __init__(self):
    print(u'конструктор класса B')
    A.__init__(self)
```

http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/4087

Comment: У вас отступы сломались, примеры стали невалидными